# Parse string as array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP and could not find a proper answer to this.

```
$whatever = "array('Test','Blah')";
echo $parsed[2]; //This will be "Blah"
```

I want to create a variable called `$parsed` which contains `$whatever`'s value but as a valid array instead of a string.

I'm aware I can just create the array by removing the quotation marks around it like this:

```
$whatever = array('Test','Blah');
```

In the actual code I'm working on, though, this isn't a possibility. Also, in my actual code, the array is multidimensional, so something involving a character replacement would probably be impractical, however I'm not ruling it out if it's the best option.

So to sum it up, what's the best way to go about parsing a string as an array in PHP?

Comment: Well is that format given or can you use another format? If you can use an other format you should have a look at [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php). Your data in JSON would look like `['Test','Blah']`.

Comment: I wonder how you get this string with `array` attached to it. Wasn't it some brilliant idea to rely upon `var_export` as a naive serializer - and couldn't it be overriden with, like, sane choices (`serialize`, `json_encode`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `eval` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php.

```
$whatever = "array('Test','Blah')";
$parsed = eval("return " . $whatever . ";");
echo $parsed[1]; //This will be "Blah"
```

Be careful to check for the `$whatever` variable contents, because any PHP code can be executed.

Comment: @Florent If OP knows that only arrays will be parsed, then `eval` is ok, isn't it?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! And yes, only array-like strings will be passing through this.

Comment: yes that work but using `eval()` is not safe so use Regular Expression if possible see my answer

Comment: I think regular expressions are not well adapted to this situation, as it can quickly become remarkably complicated : `array('test', "test2", array('test3', 'test4\'quoted\''))`

Answer (score 5):

The more secure way (without eval) is:

```
$whatever = "array('Test','Blah')";

$search = array("array", "(", ")", "'");
$parsed = explode(',',str_replace($search, '', $whatever));

echo $parsed[1];
```

This will remove all unnecessary text and then it will explode the string with the comma delimiter.

Comment: this would not handle recursive arrays, though.

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` is evil. It has poor performance and is **not safe**

So if your array is no so complex use **Regular Expression**

```
$subject = "array('Test','Blah','Blah2','Blah3')";
$pattern = "/'(.*?)'/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo "<pre>";print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: it will not work for recursive array but you can do it with some efforts

Comment: be careful to check for the two different quote characters ' and ".

Comment: Also, be careful of escaped quotes in the strings :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I have been working on. There are no unit tests yet, but it seems to work pretty well. I do not support the use of functions, instantiation of objects, conditionals etc from within the array structure. I don't want to support those for my use case. But feel free to add whatever functionality you need.

```
/**
 * A class used convert string representations or php arrays to an array without using eval()
 */
class ArrayTokenScanner
{
    /** @var array  */
    protected $arrayKeys = [];

    /**
     * @param string $string   e.g. array('foo' => 123, 'bar' => [0 => 123, 1 => 12345])
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function scan($string)
    {
        // Remove whitespace and semi colons
        $sanitized = trim($string, " \t\n\r\0\x0B;");
        if(preg_match('/^(\[|array\().*(\]|\))$/', $sanitized)) {
            if($tokens = $this->tokenize("<?php {$sanitized}")) {
                $this->initialize($tokens);
                return $this->parse($tokens);
            }
        }

        // Given array format is invalid
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid array format.");
    }

    /**
     * @param array $tokens
     */
    protected function initialize(array $tokens)
    {
        $this->arrayKeys = [];
        while($current = current($tokens)) {
            $next = next($tokens);
            if($next[0] === T_DOUBLE_ARROW) {
                $this->arrayKeys[] = $current[1];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $tokens
     * @return array
     */
    protected function parse(array &$tokens)
    {
        $array = [];
        $token = current($tokens);
        if(in_array($token[0], [T_ARRAY, T_BRACKET_OPEN])) {

            // Is array!
            $assoc = false;
            $index = 0;
            $discriminator = ($token[0] === T_ARRAY) ? T_ARRAY_CLOSE : T_BRACKET_CLOSE;
            while($token = $this->until($tokens, $discriminator)) {


                // Skip arrow ( => )
                if(in_array($token[0], [T_DOUBLE_ARROW])) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Reset associative array key
                if($token[0] === T_COMMA_SEPARATOR) {
                    $assoc = false;
                    continue;
                }

                // Look for array keys
                $next = next($tokens);
                prev($tokens);
                if($next[0] === T_DOUBLE_ARROW) {
                    // Is assoc key
                    $assoc = $token[1];
                    if(preg_match('/^-?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/', $assoc)) {
                        $index = $assoc = (int) $assoc;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                // Parse array contents recursively
                if(in_array($token[0], [T_ARRAY, T_BRACKET_OPEN])) {
                    $array[($assoc !== false) ? $assoc : $this->createKey($index)] = $this->parse($tokens);
                    continue;
                }

                // Parse atomic string
                if(in_array($token[0], [T_STRING, T_NUM_STRING, T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING])) {
                    $array[($assoc !== false) ? $assoc : $this->createKey($index)] = $this->parseAtomic($token[1]);
                }

                // Parse atomic number
                if(in_array($token[0], [T_LNUMBER, T_DNUMBER])) {

                    // Check if number is negative
                    $prev = prev($tokens);
                    $value = $token[1];
                    if($prev[0] === T_MINUS) {
                        $value = "-{$value}";
                    }
                    next($tokens);

                    $array[($assoc !== false) ? $assoc : $this->createKey($index)] = $this->parseAtomic($value);
                }

                // Increment index unless a associative key is used. In this case we want too reuse the current value.
                if(!is_string($assoc)) {
                    $index++;
                }
            }

            return $array;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $tokens
     * @param int|string $discriminator
     *
     * @return array|false
     */
    protected function until(array &$tokens, $discriminator)
    {
        $next = next($tokens);
        if($next === false or $next[0] === $discriminator) {
            return false;
        }

        return $next;
    }

    protected function createKey(&$index)
    {
        do {
            if(!in_array($index, $this->arrayKeys, true)) {
                return $index;
            }
        } while(++$index);
    }

    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return array|false
     */
    protected function tokenize($string)
    {
        $tokens = token_get_all($string);
        if(is_array($tokens)) {

            // Filter tokens
            $tokens = array_values(array_filter($tokens, [$this, 'accept']));

            // Normalize token format, make syntax characters look like tokens for consistent parsing
            return $this->normalize($tokens);

        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to accept or deny tokens so that we only have to deal with the allowed tokens
     *
     * @param array|string $value    A token or syntax character
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function accept($value)
    {
        if(is_string($value)) {
            // Allowed syntax characters: comma's and brackets.
            return in_array($value, [',', '[', ']', ')', '-']);
        }
        if(!in_array($value[0], [T_ARRAY, T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, T_DOUBLE_ARROW, T_STRING, T_NUM_STRING, T_LNUMBER, T_DNUMBER])) {
            // Token did not match requirement. The token is not listed in the collection above.
            return false;
        }
        // Token is accepted.
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Normalize tokens so that each allowed syntax character looks like a token for consistent parsing.
     *
     * @param array $tokens
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function normalize(array $tokens)
    {
        // Define some constants for consistency. These characters are not "real" tokens.
        defined('T_MINUS')           ?: define('T_MINUS',           '-');
        defined('T_BRACKET_OPEN')    ?: define('T_BRACKET_OPEN',    '[');
        defined('T_BRACKET_CLOSE')   ?: define('T_BRACKET_CLOSE',   ']');
        defined('T_COMMA_SEPARATOR') ?: define('T_COMMA_SEPARATOR', ',');
        defined('T_ARRAY_CLOSE')     ?: define('T_ARRAY_CLOSE',     ')');

        // Normalize the token array
        return array_map( function($token) {

            // If the token is a syntax character ($token[0] will be string) than use the token (= $token[0]) as value (= $token[1]) as well.
            return [
                0 => $token[0],
                1 => (is_string($token[0])) ? $token[0] : $token[1]
            ];

        }, $tokens);
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function parseAtomic($value)
    {
        // If the parameter type is a string than it will be enclosed with quotes
        if(preg_match('/^["\'].*["\']$/', $value)) {
            // is (already) a string
            return $value;
        }

        // Parse integer
        if(preg_match('/^-?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/', $value)) {
            return (int) $value;
        }

        // Parse other sorts of numeric values (floats, scientific notation etc)
        if(is_numeric($value)) {
            return  (float) $value;
        }

        // Parse bool
        if(in_array(strtolower($value), ['true', 'false'])) {
            return ($value == 'true') ? true : false;
        }

        // Parse null
        if(strtolower($value) === 'null') {
            return null;
        }

        // Use string for any remaining values.
        // For example, bitsets are not supported. 0x2,1x2 etc
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$tokenScanner = new ArrayTokenScanner();
$array = $tokenScanner->scan('[array("foo" => -123, "foobie" => "5x2", "bar" => \'456\', 111 => 12, "bar", ["null" => null], "bool" => false), 123 => E_ERROR];');
$arrayExport = preg_replace('/[\s\t]+/', ' ', var_export($array, true));
echo stripslashes($arrayExport) . PHP_EOL;
$array2 = $tokenScanner->scan('[array("foo" => 123, "foobie" => "5x2", "bar" => \'456\', 111 => 12, "bar", ["null" => null], "bool" => false), 123 => E_ERROR];');
$arrayExport = preg_replace('/[\s\t]+/', ' ', var_export($array, true));
echo stripslashes($arrayExport);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write

```
$strCreateArray = "$whatever = " . "array('Test','Blah')" . ";";

eval( $strCreateArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

If eval isn't an option. Depending if the array always has then same formatting(never multidimensional), use a replace function to remove `array(` and `)` and all quotes. And then do a string explode on the commas.

Is there no way you can not have this formatting for those arrays? Makes no sense to me to ever have arrays stored like this. Serialization or json are nicer options.

Comment: I confess I'd prefer `eval` to essentially writing my own PHP data structure parser.

Comment: @raina77ow , I hope everybody does whenever eval is available and not against company policy.