# Eval on a certain array part

Tags: php

Ok I been looking online for a few hours and i'm confused how eval() can be used in my situation so I know eval is evil but I need

and I want to use eval still for personal reasons so how can I get the variable $part to work properly like this.

```
$numbers= array($part);
```

Which means this

```
$numbers= array(4,6,2,22,11);
```

but it is not working so how can I do this with eval? and this is my failed code.

```
<?php

$part= eval(4,6,2,22,11);

$numbers= array($part);

sort($numbers);

$arrlength=count($numbers);

$output='';

for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {
$output .= $numbers[$x].'<br>';
}

echo $output;

?>
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\path\example.php on line 3
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: `eval` is intended to be used on a string. I don't see why it needs to be used in any way here. Even if you had the string `"4,6,2,22,11"`, you can just split on commas to make that to the equivalent array.

Comment: @daremachine sorry I for got to put the error and I just updated the post with the error.

Comment: also "4,6,2" is not php code. It can be "array(4,6,2)" as string.

Comment: I know daremachine its not code even if I had it like this $part= eval('4,6,2,22,11'); in a string form it still would not work.

Comment: try eval("\$numbers = array(4,6,2)"); Also you can not set result of eval because it return nothing in php 7.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I know what you mean but I need to use eval with this code even if you know it is not the right method to do this in but I still will like to know how for personal reasons.

Comment: daremachine I know it will work like that but I still want to use a variable like this in the $numbers= array($part); i'm just curious how this can be done.

Comment: look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212796/parse-string-as-array-in-php. Eval only run string as php code and your use is wrong because 2,4,6 is not array and in php is not code.

Answer (score 0):

[Eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) only run string as php code and your use is wrong because 2,4,6 is not code in php language. How documentation says

> eval - Evaluate a string as PHP code

This will work.

```
$stringNumbers = "4,6,2,22,11";

$part= eval("return array(\".$stringNumbers.\");");

$numbers= $part;
```